# Schengen visa expiring on April 12, 2018

Tags: romania

I'm a Saudi citizen, holding a Schengen visa that expires on April 12, 2018. I'm planning to visit Romania, which allows multiple entries for Schengen visa holders. However my Schengen visa is expiring in 1 month and I'm planning to visa Bucharest on March 25 for 5 days.

Is it ok to enter that country with 15 days left on the visa?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be okay?